Replace optoisolator with a MOSFET
I need to turn on a Raspberry Pi Zero with two signals (OR logic gate): one is 3.3 V and one is 5.0 V.
I designed a circuit (that is simply doubled, so that any of the two signals can turn it on) using two optoisolators. However, the two optoisolators' Ic is 50 mA, while the Raspberry requires 1A.
I searched a bit, and found out that MOSFETs do exactly this job, but I could not reliably figure out a circuit design to accomplish the job.
My uncertainty comes from the fact that MOSFETs have 3 pins. if one pin is ground, one pin receives the 3.3 V signal to turn on the MOSFET, what does the third pin do? How can it supply 5 V to the load? It can either receive or "give" 5 V to the load, not both. I'm confused.
For the sake of simplicity, let's design one circuit only with one 3.3 V signal only that is supposed to turn on the Raspberry Pi (then one could simply put two circuits that turn on the Raspberry with an OR logic gate).
Here is the original design with an optoisolator:

Here is the new circuit, but I'm not sure I understood correctly how MOSFETs work. Also, how do I determine the values of R1 and R2?


Are you trying to power up the Raspberry Pi through its 5V pin? If yes, I think it is a bad idea. You should just power it up through the provided USB type C power adapter.

Could you explain why is that?

There are two ways to control DC power to a device - switch the DC, or switch the GND.  To switch the GND you normally use an NPN bipolar transistor or an n-channel MOSFET.  That probably is what you are thinking of.
To switch the DC, the circuit is called a high-side switch.  This is done with a PNP transistor or a p-channel MOSFET.  The source goes to the 5 V supply, the drain goes to the device, and the gate is pulled to GND to "turn on" (fully enhance) the FET.
Because your control signal is only 3.3 V, there is no guarantee that the FET will be 100% off when the control signal is high.  To fix this, we add a driver transistor.
UPDATE:
Based on something I did for someone else, here is a schematic that uses a 3.3 V control signal to switch a 5 V source to a load.  Note that the component part numbers and values can be adjusted for what you have available.  The important part is that Q2 be a p-channel logic-level MOSFET.  Compared to a "normal" MOSFET, this type requires a lower gate voltage for full enhancement.

Update 2:
If logic level FETs are hard to find, either or both transistors can be changes to bipolar types, such as a 2N4401 and a TIP32.  Each bipolar transistor would require one additional resistor.
Update 3:
The 2N7000 has a Threshold Voltage of 3 V worst case. Because the required drain current is so low, the Transfer Characteristic plot shows that it is "on" enough for reliable operation in this circuit at 3.3 V, so that is the minimum operational input voltage. The part is rated for a max Vgs of 20 V, so that is the max input. It will take a 5 V signal easily. If that 3 V Vth is a concern because that is only 0.3 V of operating margin, change Q1 to a 2N4401, 2N3904, 2N2222, etc. with a base resistor.
https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nds7002a-d.pdf

Many thanks! Could you elaborate on how the circuit you posted works, please, so that I fully understand the logic? Also, how are the resistors calculated? I have available IRFZ44N in place of the 2n7000 and a IRF740 in place of the IRFR9024. The datasheets are similar, but I’m not sure

While both of those parts are way overkill in terms of voltage and current, neither are logic level devices.  You can see this in the datasheet, in a parameter called Threshold Voltage.  This is the gate-source voltage when the FET just barely starts to conduct.  For your circuit we want this to be below 3 V.  Also, the 740 is an n-channel part.  See Update 2.

Threshold voltage is the minimum voltage to “trigger” the mosfet, right? Thank you again for helping.

Not Trigger.  A FET is a linear, or analog device, basically a voltage-variable resistor.  The threshold voltage is when the FET begins to conduct.  As the gate voltage increases, it conducts more and more.  Eventually it is at its maximum conductance, the minimum possible value of its resistance from drain to source, called Rdson.  This can be a small fraction of one ohm.  So a power MOSFET can go from a megohm of resistance to less than one ohm as Vgs increases a few volts.

Sorry, one last question. If I have a 5v signal to trigger the MOSFET, can I simply use a voltage divider to bring it down to 3.3v and use the same circuit? The 3.3v are connected to the 2N7000's gate, correct?

See Update 3. . .
